# SLD From QGIS in Geoserver - Displacement error

Tags: geoserver, sld

I generated SLD style from QGIS software, and here is my final SLD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
                       xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
                       xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
                       xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
                       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>google_polygon</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>'Polygon'</Title>
      <!--TAG-->
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Name>water</Name>
        <Rule>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:Or>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>natural</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>water</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>waterway</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>riverbank</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:Or>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#b6d9ff</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>forest &amp; park</Name>

      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:Or>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>landuse</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>forest</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>leisure</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>park</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:Or>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#cbdfaa</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>

    <Rule>
      <Name>industrial</Name>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:Or>
          <ogc:Not>
            <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
              <ogc:PropertyName>aeroway</ogc:PropertyName>
            </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
          </ogc:Not>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>landuse</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>industrial</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:Or>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#e9e6de</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>residential</Name>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>landuse</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>residential</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#e9e6db</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>

    <Rule>
      <Name>building</Name>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:Not>
          <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
            <ogc:PropertyName>building</ogc:PropertyName>
          </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
        </ogc:Not>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <MinScaleDenominator>1</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>15000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.12</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
        *<Displacement>
          <DisplacementX>1</DisplacementX>
          <DisplacementY>1</DisplacementY>
        </Displacement>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.20</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
        *<Displacement>
          <DisplacementX>-1</DisplacementX>
          <DisplacementY>-1</DisplacementY>
        </Displacement>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#dddad4</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
  </FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```

After validation in Geoserver 2.10.2 this style I got this errors:

> line 109: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Displacement'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/sld":Stroke}' is expected.
>
> line 119: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Displacement'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/sld":Stroke}' is expected.

Lines 109 and 119 I marked in code with '*'.

Can you help me to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to offset the polygon, you could remove the displacement bit from the xml and use the [offset](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#geometric-functions) function in geoserver as follows:

```
<PolygonSymbolizer>
    <Geometry>
        <ogc:Function name="offset">
            <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
    </Geometry>        
    <Fill>
        <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.12</CssParameter>
    </Fill>
</PolygonSymbolizer>
```